# How can you send text to a Google Hangouts window then alt-tab to another window and keep on sending text to the minimized window, in AutoHotKey?

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I want to spam my friend (I'm a great friend, I know hahahaaa) in Google Hangouts. The twist is, I want alt-tab to another window and I want the spammer to run in the background to spam my friend. Here's my code:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetBatchLines -1 ; maximum speed

^!m:: ; Ctrl + Alt + m: starts the spammer
sleep 500
BreakLoop := 0 ; 0 - Don't break the loop, 1 - Break the loop
Loop {
    if (BreakLoop = 1) {
        BreakLoop := 0
        break

    }
    ControlSend,, text to spam, Google Hangouts - Google Chrome ; types the text
    ControlSend,, {enter}, Google Hangouts - Google Chrome ; sends the text
    sleep 5000 ; spams every 5 seconds
    return
}


Esc:: ; stops the spammer
    BreakLoop := 1
    sleep 500
    return
```

The problem is that I can't get it to work. When I alt tab to another window, it doesn't send or type the text. How do I fix that? Thanks in advance and sorry if my code is messy. Also, I am using the latest version of AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that this isn't really possible with AHK. AutoHotkey simulates keyboard and mouse input, and while you can get more advanced with JavaScript calls, the Hangouts window itself is still going to need to be the active window for any text input that AutoHotkey generates, and you can't use the keyboard/mouse while it's doing its thing.

You're likely better off performing this via Javascript in the Hangouts web client in Gmail, or y'know, just not spamming people altogether.